# Woocommerce New Account link and Reset Password link is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, reset-password

I have a WooCommerce website and it is a normal store, I am using sendgrid as my SMTP and it works as it sends the emails of the website immediately but there is one issue I am facing which is not related to the theme as it is coming in the default wordpress themes too. The issue is when i create a new account without password it normally sends an email to set a password but the link to set the password is not correct as it looks like this (http://url852.onetaponly.com/ls/click?upn=yvt6wI-2FyFFrwf0lBoRBJBoJzxglE3ZRmZB2CYZEaT8bcPR6mnT2OrYVCXHsCqxaDf14-2FWhIjhkxtl-2FrtI4Q3-2FJGWgP9uryUhaa-2FBGVzX4AJUMUjXfMYB3R3txE3xrkgVDKdMz3O51Hp2MFGiBL6dxw-3D-3D8bhR_CD7oeHp-2Fd8w-2BETjH148ZyCK7qmgHiVVwm7Q-2B5ez4) instead of this (https://onetaponly.com/my-account/lost-password/?action=newaccount&key=$key)
I have seen the email template and it looks correct as it has a variable set_password_url which is inserted inside the link, now I do not know where the issue is coming from and how to solve.

I tried looking into the plugin WooCommerce code for the email template and New_Account class but it seems correct, I also changed the theme to see if is related to the theme but it isn't.